# Display number as currency

Tags: carto

Is there any way to display a number as currency in the hover window? I'd like the  value to read “$5.6 million” rather than “5555555,” for example.

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve this you need to recreate what you need in another column (of type string) and enable this new column in your infowindows.

The way that infowindows work at the moment inside the CartoDB Editor is just adding the information of your table, which means that you cannot process the strings there.

To populate your new column with something useful for your infowindows, you can use a SQL query like:

```
UPDATE tablename SET new_column_name = '$'|| trunc((old_column::numeric/1000000), 1)  ||' million'
```

This allows you to truncate the millions with 1 decimal, but you can edit that if needed. Documentation about mathematical functions and operators [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-math.html).

I'm assuming your current column is of type string. If it's of type number you can get rid of the cast in your column (but needed in the trunc() parameter!):

```
UPDATE tablename SET new_column_name = '$'|| trunc((old_column/1000000)::numeric, 1)  ||' million'
```

To finish, just add your new column into your infowindow. :-)